# How to handle input parameters while generating dynamic html from jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic-html

I am using below function to generate dynamic HTML.

```
function (content) {
    $('#divMessage').append('<span>'+ content+ '</span>');
}
```

Here I am appending content in div with id **divMessage**.

Here input parameter **content** can be any text passed to this function.

I am facing problem when I pass data containing html elements as it distorts html. I am not aable to paste it here as its get dostorted here in stack overflow editor as well.

How can I resolve this issue, TIA.

[image]

It should append what is being passed, don't want to convert html tags to html, if html tag with data is passed then html tag with data should be the ouput.

Comment: input parameter like:       p += '<div class="chat-details" ' + _float + ' ><label class="name ' + _pull + '">' + _name + '</label>';

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "distorted" please?

Comment: Please provide a **runnable** [mcve] and explain problem in more detail

Comment: its not generating exact html..

Comment: *"its not generating exact html"* .... what exactly does that mean?

Comment: i have passed paramter:          _p += '<div class="chat-details" ' + _float + ' ><label class="name ' + _pull + '">' + _name + '</label>'; and got result shown in above image.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this you need to only paser the content text to HTML

Just do this

```
    content= $.parseHTML(content);
$('#divMessage').append('<span>'+ content+ '</span>');
```

Hope it will help!

Comment: output should be <span> _p += '<div class="chat-details" ' + _float + ' ><label class="name ' + _pull + '">' + _name + '</label>';</span>

Comment: Take all these things"_p += '<div class="chat-details" ' + _float + ' ><label class="name ' + _pull + '">' + _name + '</label>" in on variable then parse it .so that all the values on the variable also converted to html
like:-'<div class="chat-details" ' + _float + ' > will be equal to '<div class="chat-details text"' > if  _float='text'.

Comment: thanks @Sahoo but I fixed it by 1st creating span then using its text property to add content in it..

Answer (score 0):

You can pass html value like this.

```js
function AddContent(content) {
    $('#divMessage').append('<span>'+ content+ '</span>');
}
$("#divAppendMessage").on("click", function() {
    //$('#divMessage').html(''); // If you want to clear div before append
   var html='';
   html+='<h1>My new message</h1>';// You can add mark up like this.Be sure for closing tag.
   AddContent('<h1>My new message</h1>');// Pass html without generate markup as OP say on comment.
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='divMessage'>
</div>
<button id='divAppendMessage'>Add Message</button>
```

May be 
[this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h1ctc2L9/) solve your problem. Before get input from user convert it and reset it when bind.

Comment: I don't want to convert html tags, just want to show what is being passed as an parameter..

Comment: if I pass <h1>My new message</h1> then ouput should be <h1>My new message</h1>(same)..

Comment: As your comment I pass html and it's work see updated snippet.

Comment: you are generating html with h1 tag but I want html as "<h1>My new message</h1>"

Comment: I am working on chat application and want to send message what is being passed.., dont want to convert it in html..